# converting html into text

Tags: jsf, jsoup, rich-text-editor

I am working with JSF. I have used RichFaces's 'RichEditor'. I am storing contents from this editor into a bean and displaying into a JSF form. But it shows HTML tags on the JSF form. For that I have used JSoup HTML Parser. But it completely converts the written content of the rich editor  to simple text, removing all formatting like bold, buttons used, newline, etc.  I need to display as it is in the jSF form as the editor.

Please help...

CODE for Rich Editor

```
            <f:param name="theme_advanced_buttons1" value="
            newdocument,separator,copy,cut,paste,pasteword,undo,redo,separator,bold,italic,underline,
            strikethrough,forecolor,backcolor,separator,
            justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,outdent,indent " />

        <f:param name="theme_advanced_buttons2" value= "bullist,numlist,separator,
        insertdate,inserttime,separator,image,emotions,styleprops,fontselect,fontsizeselect,formatselect,search,replace"/>  

        <f:param name="theme_advanced_toolbar_location" value="top"/>                               
        <f:param name="theme_advanced_toolbar_align" value="left"/>
        <f:param name="theme_advanced_font_sizes" value="10px,12px,14px,16px,18px,20px,24px,32px,36px,42px,48px,60px,72px"/>
        <f:param name="theme_advanced_fonts" value="Andale Mono=andale mono,times;
            Arial=arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
            Arial Black=arial black,avant garde;
            Book Antiqua=book antiqua,palatino;
            Calibri=calibri;
            Comic Sans MS=comic sans ms,sans-serif;
            Courier New=courier new,courier;
            Georgia=georgia,palatino;
            Helvetica=helvetica;
            Impact=impact,chicago;
            Symbol=symbol;
            Tahoma=tahoma,arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
            Terminal=terminal,monaco;
            Times New Roman=times new roman,times;
            Trebuchet MS=trebuchet ms,geneva;
            Verdana=verdana,geneva;
            Webdings=webdings;
            Wingdings=wingdings,zapf dingbats"/>

        </rich:editor>
```

FROM Java....

public String saveNotice()
    {

```
    System.out.println(html2text(editor));



    return "";

}


public  String html2text(String editor)
{
    String edit;


    edit=Jsoup.parse(editor).text();
    setEditor(edit);
    return edit;


}
```

Comment: Can you give us a link to a demo or some page source code from your browser? That would be more helpful for the persons who wants help.

Answer (score 1):

When you're redisplaying it using `<h:outputText>`, JSF will escape them in order to prevent XSS attacks. You need to add `escape="false"` to redisplay the HTML plain (which thus get interpreted by the webbrowser).

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.html}" escape="false" />
```

However, this is still a potential XSS hole. Since you're already using [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org), you can use [`Jsoup#clean()`](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/cleaning-html/whitelist-sanitizer) to preserve some basic HTML tags and remove all other malicious tags.

```
public String sanitizeHtml(String html) {
    return Jsoup.clean(unsafe, Whitelist.basic());
}
```

The `Whitelist` is customizeable. See also [its javadoc](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/safety/Whitelist.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

in your source the open tag of rich editor is missing. According [editors homepage](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_editor.html) try to add the viewMode parameter. I think the value of it must be 'visual'.